# How to perform arithmetic calculation between rows in oracle Pl/Sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Table A

| Subject | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 200 |
| C | 400 |
| D | 500 |

Table B

| Subject | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| A | A/B |
| B | B/D |
| C | D/A-B |
| D | A+B/C-D |

Output

| Subject | Result |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.5 |
| B | 0.4 |
| C | 5 |
| D | 3 |

Comment: I don't think dumping formulas as strings into a particular column is feasible and having much sense, rather using some PL/SQL code blocks with such formulas is a pretty better idea...

Answer (score 1):

Let's build a parser in SQL....

1. Implement the shunting yard algorithm as a recursive sub-query; and then
2. Take the reverse polish output from the shunting yard and use it to calculate the value.

```sql
WITH shunting_yard (subject, formula, stack, output) AS (
  SELECT subject,
         formula,
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(4000)),
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(4000))
  FROM   B
UNION ALL
  SELECT subject,
         CASE
         WHEN SUBSTR(formula, 1, 1) NOT IN ('+', '-', '/', '*')
         THEN SUBSTR(formula, 2)
         WHEN stack IS NULL
         OR   DECODE(SUBSTR(stack, -1), '+', 1, '-', 1, '/', '2', '*', '2')
            < DECODE(SUBSTR(formula, 1, 1), '+', 1, '-', 1, '/', '2', '*', '2')
         THEN SUBSTR(formula, 2)
         ELSE formula
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN SUBSTR(formula, 1, 1) NOT IN ('+', '-', '/', '*')
         THEN stack
         WHEN stack IS NULL
         OR   DECODE(SUBSTR(stack, -1), '+', 1, '-', 1, '/', '2', '*', '2')
            < DECODE(SUBSTR(formula, 1, 1), '+', 1, '-', 1, '/', '2', '*', '2')
         THEN SUBSTR(formula, 1, 1) || stack
         ELSE SUBSTR(stack, 2)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN SUBSTR(formula, 1, 1) NOT IN ('+', '-', '/', '*')
         THEN output || SUBSTR(formula, 1, 1)
         WHEN stack IS NULL
         OR   DECODE(SUBSTR(stack, -1), '+', 1, '-', 1, '/', '2', '*', '2')
            < DECODE(SUBSTR(formula, 1, 1), '+', 1, '-', 1, '/', '2', '*', '2')
         THEN output
         ELSE output || SUBSTR(stack, 1, 1)
         END
  FROM   shunting_yard
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY subject, formula SET order_id
CYCLE subject, formula, stack, output SET done TO 1 DEFAULT 0,
reverse_polish (subject, formula, stack, value) AS (
  SELECT subject,
         output,
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(4000)),
         CAST(NULL AS NUMBER)
  FROM   shunting_yard
  WHERE  done = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT r.subject,
         SUBSTR(r.formula, 2),
         CASE
         WHEN SUBSTR(r.formula, 1, 1) IN ('+', '-', '*', '/')
         THEN '_' || SUBSTR(r.stack, 3)
         ELSE SUBSTR(r.formula, 1, 1) || r.stack
         END,
         CASE SUBSTR(r.formula, 1, 1)
         WHEN '+'
         THEN COALESCE(a2.marks, r.value) + COALESCE(a1.marks, r.value)
         WHEN '-'
         THEN COALESCE(a2.marks, r.value) - COALESCE(a1.marks, r.value)
         WHEN '/'
         THEN COALESCE(a2.marks, r.value) / COALESCE(a1.marks, r.value)
         WHEN '*'
         THEN COALESCE(a2.marks, r.value) * COALESCE(a1.marks, r.value)
         ELSE r.value
         END
  FROM   reverse_polish r
         LEFT OUTER JOIN a a1
         ON SUBSTR(r.stack, 1, 1) = a1.subject
         LEFT OUTER JOIN a a2
         ON SUBSTR(r.stack, 2, 1) = a2.subject
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY subject, formula SET order_id
CYCLE subject, formula, stack SET done TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT subject, value
FROM   reverse_polish
WHERE  done = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (Subject, Marks) AS
SELECT 'A', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 500 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE B (Subject, Formula) AS
SELECT 'A', 'A/B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'B/D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'D/A-B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'A+B/C-D' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SUBJECT | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | .5 |
| B | .4 |
| C | -195 |
| D | -399.5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NOLPvJf5)

Answer (score 0):

Some results you posted (C and D) are invalid; first you have to multiply/divide, then add/subtract. For your kind of results, you'll need to use brackets.

Anyway: dynamic SQL should be used. Here's one option:

- fetch all *variables* from `table_a`
- loop through all operations in `table_b`
- replace *variables* with their values (fetched in the 1st step)
- calculate
- display result

---

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_val_a table_a.marks%type;
  3    l_val_b table_a.marks%type;
  4    l_val_c table_a.marks%type;
  5    l_val_d table_a.marks%type;
  6    --
  7    l_str varchar2(200);
  8    l_result number;
  9  begin
 10    select max(case when subject = 'A' then marks end),
 11           max(case when subject = 'B' then marks end),
 12           max(case when subject = 'C' then marks end),
 13           max(case when subject = 'D' then marks end)
 14      into l_val_a, l_val_b, l_val_c, l_val_d
 15      from table_a;
 16
 17    for cur_r in (select subject, formula
 18                  from table_b
 19                 )
 20    loop
 21      l_str := replace(replace(replace(replace(
 22                 cur_r.formula, 'A', l_val_a),
 23                                'B', l_val_b),
 24                                'C', l_val_c),
 25                                'D', l_val_d);
 26      l_str := 'select ' || l_str || ' from dual';
 27      execute immediate l_str into l_result;
 28      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.subject ||': '|| l_str ||' = '|| l_result);
 29    end loop;
 30  end;
 31  /
```

Output:

```
A: select 100/200 from dual = .5
B: select 200/500 from dual = .4
C: select 500/100+200 from dual = 205
D: select 100+200/400-500 from dual = -399.5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Is there any way we can handle this with out hardcoding the subject in query ?

Comment: You can generate the formula using a recursive query and use xmlquery to evaluate it, you just have to replace "/" by "div" and of course as others already pointed: you must take into account the order of precedence of operators and add () to get the expected results:
A  100 div 200                                  0,5

B  200 div 500                                  0,4

C  500 div( 100 - 200 )                 -5

D ( 100 + 200 )div( 400 - 500 ) -3

(On 23c you will have the choice to use Javascript eval() with a MLE module)